# How are the words "cool", "dummy" and "married" related?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

The 4 rows of words in the table below are each formed by following one rule.

| Group | Word 1 | Word 2 | Word 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | save | scar | trap |
| 2 | adore | argue | boy |
| 3 | cool | dummy | married |
| 4 | lovely | mockery | underdog |

What is the rule?

Hint 1:

> Think of this as a mathematical problem. The group numbers, they're pretty small to be math solutions right? Maybe take them as tens?

Hint 2:

> Keyboard arrangement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the two hints together gives a straightforward answer:

> Treating the row #'s as 10's and assigning each letter a value equal to the digit above it on a keyboard (Q,A,Z=1 etc) we see the rows were created by finding words that sum to that row # (* 10) (the words were then placed in alphabetical order).
>  First Example: S2 A1 V4 E3 = 10 (row 1)
>  Last Example: U7 N6 D3 E3 R4 D3 O9 G5 = 40 (row 4)

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

---

Here is a very easy answer:

> Each group is in alphabetical order.

If that is just on purpose, here is another answer:

> Every first letter in word 1, word 2, word 3, are consecutive numbers according to Scrabble tile points.

For example:

> SACL (Word 1) scores 6 points. SADM scores 7 points. The last one is TBMU, which scores 8.

Comment: You've got the word1, word2, word3 *order* right, but it still doesn't explain the *grouping rule* :D

Comment: I'll try to figure out..

Comment: Time to wait for a hint!

Answer (score 0):

> the group number for each group is (almost) the the tens place of the total score.

> save (7) + scar (6) + trap (6) = 19

> adore (6) + argue (6) + boy (8) = 20

> cool (6) + dummy (13) + married (10) = 29?

> lovely (12) + mockery (18) + underdog (11) = 41

It's clearly not quite right... but it's close?

Answer (score -3):

Group 3 - each word has a Sequentially repeated letter

another option.. in each group, words 1,2,3 are in alphabetical order?

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE! I believe you missed it, but as pointed out in my post, the 4 groups of words all have one property on common, and a repeated letter does not apply to all of them.

Comment: @riskymysteries Is getting the groups' properties and then  finding the relation through them leads to an answer? (like a connect wall)

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison The answer to this puzzle is finding out what *one* rule makes *each* group.